# How to create surfaceview with rounded corners

Tags: android, stream, surfaceview

I am having a difficulty to round the corners of surfaceview. I am using MjpegView
(custom view that inherit from surfaceview.
I tried already this solutions:
     1) set background with custom drawable with round corners
     2) After reading this post http://androidtutorialsandtips.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/overriding-ondraw-method-in-surfaceview.html
        I am not sure how to implement the round corners as I have already implemented a thread that locks the canvas.

```
while (mRun)
        {
            if (surfaceDone)
            {
                try
                {
                    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (mIn != null)
                            {
                                Bitmap bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                                destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());

                                if (streamHeight == -1 && streamWidth == -1)
                                {
                                    streamWidth = bm.getWidth();
                                    streamHeight = bm.getHeight();
                                }
                                c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                                c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                                if (showFps)
                                {
                                    p.setXfermode(mode);
                                    if (ovl != null)
                                    {
                                        height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom - ovl.getHeight();
                                        width = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right - ovl.getWidth();
                                        c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                    }
                                    p.setXfermode(null);
                                    frameCounter++;
                                    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000)
                                    {
                                        fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter) + "fps";
                                        frameCounter = 0;
                                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                        ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException e)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (c != null) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you have problems with?

Comment: I can`t round the corners of surfaceview

Comment: what is mode?  why do you set it but never use it? what are the results of your code?

Comment: I am using this view https://code.google.com/p/android-camera-axis/source/browse/trunk/serealisation/src/de/mjpegsample/MjpegView/MjpegView.java?r=33. The result is very simple, the surface view has corners and I need to remove them. I tried changing the background of the surface view but it`s not working

Comment: FWIW, any approach that recommends overriding SurfaceView's `onDraw()` is probably wrong. The SurfaceView surface is not part of the View hierarchy, and should not be tied to it. Remember that the surface is on a separate layer, behind all of the View UI, and not tied to the invalidate/refresh cycle, and things will make more sense. Placing opaque rounded corner images on an overlay, as described in an answer below, is the easiest way to do what you want.

Comment: See this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361939/how-to-set-the-surface-view-camera-background-with-corner its working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correcly:

1. create a `<FrameLayout ...>` with 2 children: the surface view and a partially transparent cover layer above it. (`FrameLayout` draws its children one on top of another.)
2. draw the rounded corners on the cover layer.

That is, you will have an opaque layer above the `SurfaceView`  and that opaque layer will have a transparent hole-with-rounded-corners in its center.

Here's an example where I cover a SurfaceView with a 50%-transparent black layer (*visibility="invisible"* by default) and a RelativeLayout with buttons inside.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/transparency"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/xxxxx"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        ...
```

Comment: Can you show me an example, I if you just add drawable with round corners in the cover layout you will still see the corners of the surfaceview

Comment: I mean, the surfaceView would be covered by a transparent image with rounded non-transparent corners. Just try to place any image above the surfaceview, then you will see what to do...

Comment: @visionixvisionix: Were you able to implement this? If yes, can you please post some sample code. In my case I want to display the camera in a circular shape

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what you ask, it is very easy to do it. You only need to use the next XML:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">
        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And to use this CardView, add this dependency on your **build.gradle** app:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```